# Unable to get error when using "try" and "except" option in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I am trying to run a code to show other errors except TypeError.

**The code I am using is as below:**

```
A = 1
B = "2"
try:
    C = A + B + D
except TypeError:
    print("Type Error")
```

**Output expected is as below:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6b5697b50966> in <module>
      1 A = 1
      2 B = 2
----> 3 C = A + B + D

NameError: name 'D' is not defined
```

However, **the actual output is as below:**

```
Type Error
```

Can someone please suggest the solution for the same?

Comment: Rewrite it as `C = A + D + B`. You'll get it now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove the try-except and got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**Explanation:** you have already caught an error trying to add `A` and `B`, therefore your code will stop executing and not find the second error.

---

**Edit:** As suggested in the comment, the `NameError` will show if you first add `A` and `D` and then `B`: `A + D + B`

**Edit2:** If you think you might have different kinds of errors one possibility (if you for example want different things to happen on a specific type of error) is to have multiple excepts like this:

```
A = 1
B = "2"
try:
    C = A + D + B
except NameError:
    print("ERROR: NameError")
except TypeError:
    print("ERROR: TypeError")
```

Which produces this output:

```
ERROR: NameError
```

Answer (score 0):

Python will first evaluate `A + B` and then add `D`. Therefore, before noticing that `D` is not defined and throwing a `NameError` python will throw a `TypeError` because the `+`-operator is not applicable to integers and strings.